# make integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, pointers

```
assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   31 |         array[kategori] = "Best Pick";
      |                         ^
t02.c:36:25: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   36 |         array[kategori] = "Must Read";
      |                         ^
t02.c:40:25: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   40 |         array[kategori] = "Recommended";
      |                         ^
t02.c:44:25: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   44 |         array[kategori] = "Average";
      |                         ^
t02.c:47:25: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   47 |         array[kategori] = "Low";
```

i want to know, what " makes integer from pointer without a cast" does mean ?

Comment: Post the faulty code.

Comment: You're assigning a pointer to an integer.  This rarely makes sense, but if you really want to force it, you need to use a cast.  In your case, it doesn't make sense.  You have a `char` array (`char` is an integer type).  You need a `char *` array (i.e., an array whose *elements* have type `char *`), or else you need to use `strcpy` to copy the strings into the array, rather than trying to force them into individual elements of the arry.

Answer (score 2):

It means you're trying to set an integer equal to a pointer, like this:

```
const char * ptrToChar = "hello";
int x = ptrToChar;   // error, trying to set an integer equal to the value of a pointer
```

Also in this case the type of the integer you're trying to set is `char` (aka a 7-bit or 8-bit integer that is commonly used to hold exactly 1 ASCII character):

```
const char * ptrToChar = "hello";
char x = ptrToChar;  // error, trying to set a char equal to a (const char *)
```

From the looks of the warnings you are getting, the `char` you're trying to set is a member of a char-array, so probably it's more like this:

```
int kategori = 3;
char array[20];   // each element of (array) is a char
array[kategori] = "Recommended"; // error, trying to set a char equal to a (const char *)
```

Since each element in `array` is a char, you can only really store a char in it, like this:

```
array[kategori] = 'R';  // ok (note single quotes around 'R')
```

... if you wanted to copy an entire string into `array`, you could do it character-by-character, using a for-loop, or use a libC-supplied function like `strncpy()` to do it for you:

```
strncpy(array, "Recommended", sizeof(array));
```

Setting an integer to the value of a pointer is technically possible (sort of), but it almost never makes sense to do that, which is why the compiler is warning you that you are trying to have it do something that you probably didn't really intend.

Comment: It was a good answer until you dragged in the dangerous `strncpy` function. `strncpy(array, "Recommended", sizeof(array));` is dangerous and a latent bug. Avoid `strncpy` and use safer functions like `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead. Or if you must, non-standard `strcpy_s`/`strlcpy`.

Comment: @Lundin I think referring to `strcpy()` and `memcpy()` as "safer functions" must be a typo, since they are even less safe than `strncpy()` :)

Comment: It's not a typo, they are considerably safer. [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518)

Comment: `strncpy()` is dangerous because it can leave the destination buffer not-NULL-terminated, which might lead to latter code reading past the end of the destination buffer, if it doesn't account for the possibility of an unterminated string.  `strcpy()` and `memcpy()` are worse because they will blindly write past the end of the destination buffer, corrupting memory and directly providing an opportunity for code injection.

Really, working with variable-length strings in C at all is dangerous; but the only good solution is to move to C++ and use std::string or similar.

Comment: std::string can't sanitize program input either, because it is a string class and it is not it's job or purpose. The problem isn't C or `strcpy` but confused people mixing up input sanitation with string handling as if they are somehow related. - The bouncer at the club lets drunk people in. You get punched in the head by a drunk person. Wearing a helmet when visiting clubs isn't the solution. Educate the bouncer so that they do their job proper is the solution. I won't listen to any more "you used the wrong helmet brand" arguments.

Comment: How many concussions should every new bouncer suffer before he gains enough experience to do his job properly?